# C# SqlCeDataReader rdata FieldCount

Tags: c#, sql, database, sql-server-ce

I am trying to see if an ID exists in a database in this case it's vetID.

To see if the result of the SQL query is successfull I am trying to use **rdata.FieldCount**

FieldCount always seems to return 11 even if the input ID (variable i) is = -400 (an id number that cannot exist in the database). I have also tried with other numbers that are not possible such as 100 or 800 (the database has only  1 - 5  items in it)

```
var mySQLCommand = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM vets WHERE vetID = @ID", dbCon);
mySQLCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("ID", i);
SqlCeDataReader rdata = mySQLCommand.ExecuteReader();
if (rdata.FieldCount >= 1) 
{
    MessageBox.Show(" HAS ROWS "); go = true; 
}
else 
{ 
    MessageBox.Show("NO ROWS RETURNED"); 
}
MessageBox.Show("rdata FieldCount " + rdata.FieldCount + " i has value " + i);
```

Is there a more elegant way to check an ID is still valid in the database and has not been deleted?

OK.. before you call me Stupid ... im guessing the FieldCount is just the exactly that the FieldCount and not the FieldCount of the returned Query ... doh...

But the question still stands is there an elegant way to know if the ID is still there in the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a datareader you can't get a rowcount using fieldcount.  But if you wanted to leave the query the same you'd do:

```
var mySQLCommand = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM vets WHERE vetID = @ID", dbCon);
mySQLCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("ID", i);
SqlCeDataReader rdata = mySQLCommand.ExecuteReader();
if (rdata.read() ) 
{
    MessageBox.Show(" HAS ROWS "); 
go = true; 
}
else 
{ 
    MessageBox.Show("NO ROWS RETURNED"); 
}
MessageBox.Show("rdata FieldCount " + rdata.FieldCount + " i has value " + i);
```

Another way to check is to use a `select count(*)` to see if it's in the table and that would be 0 if it doesn't exist.

```
var mySQLCommand = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT count(*) FROM vets WHERE vetID = @ID", dbCon);
            mySQLCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("ID", i);
            SqlCeDataReader rdata = mySQLCommand.ExecuteReader();
int rowCount = 0;
if ( rdata.read() ) {
    rowCount = rdata[0];
}
```

Comment: SqlCeDataReader rdata  does not have RowCount, could you elabourate more on the SELECT Count(*) please

Comment: var mySQLCommand = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT count(*) FROM vets WHERE vetID = @ID", dbCon);

Comment: ExecuteReader is no where near the most efficient way to do this particular operation.

Answer (score 4):

FieldCount always returns 11 because (I assume) there are 11 columns in the table.

A better way is:

```
var sql = new SqlCeCommand("select top 1 vetid from vets where vetid = @id", dbCon);
sql.Paramaters.AddWithValue("id", i);
if (null != mySqlCommand.ExecuteScalar())
{
   // ID exists
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An sql reader is a forward reader only - so you cannot get the number of rows form a property. `FieldCount` is the number of columns in the current record. The only way to the get the number of rows returned is to read them all in or to run a `count` query before hand (which might not be concurrency safe)

Answer (score -1):

Try using the `HasRows` property instead:

```
if (rdata.HasRows) 
{
    MessageBox.Show(" HAS ROWS "); go = true; 
}
else
{ 
    MessageBox.Show("NO ROWS RETURNED"); 
}
```